# Variable Name is undefined

Tags: python

When I run this program, I keep getting an error saying that `fahrenheit` is not defined.

Here's the code:

```
def morning():
celsius = int(input('How many degrees C is the temperature in the morning: '))
fahrenheit = 9 / 5 * celsius + 32
return fahrenheit


print('%.1f' % fahrenheit + "F")

morning()


def evening():
celsius = int(input("How many degrees C is the temperature in the evening: "))
fahrenheit = 9 / 5 * celsius + 32
return fahrenheit


print('%.1f' % fahrenheit + "F")

evening()

for i in range(0, 1):
if i is 0:
    morning()
else:
    evening()

    if fahrenheit <= 79:
        print("This morning is cold")
    else:
        if fahrenheit <= 90:
            print("It is a little warm this morning")
        else:
            print("It is quite hot today")

if fahrenheit <= 79:
    print("Tonight is cold")
else:
    if efahrenheit <= 90:
        print("It is a little warm this evening")
    else:
        print("It is quite hot tonight")

if fahrenheit and efahrenheit <= 79:
    print("It was cold today")
else:
    if fahrenheit and efahrenheit <= 90:
        print("The weather was warm today")
    else:
        print("Today was quite hot today")
```

Comment: Maybe try calling `morning()` before calling `print(...)`. Same with `evening()`. And assign the values that these functions return to something, like: `fahrenheit = morning()` so that you're not using some "leftover" value that was assigned inside a function.

Comment: Also, you are using `efahrenheit` at some point in your code and that has not been defined.

Comment: i was trying to use efahrenheit as a different variable as to avoid mixup in the following comparisons in the "for" loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you're declaring the `fahrenheit` variable inside the methods, but you're trying to use it outside of them.
To be allowed to do it, you need to create it out of the method.
For example, like this:

```
fahrenheit = morning()
```

Now, you can work with that varaible

Comment: this made the code work fine, but it needs ALOT of cleaning up to work as i had in mind.(several inputs are demanded in the code, i think i need to re-edit it.)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code, except last if/else block, all other working fine and single function is used for all.

def temp():

```
cel_morn = float(input("Enter morning temperature in degrees:"))
fah_morn = (9/5 * cel_morn) + 32
print("Temperature in Fahrenheit ", fah_morn)

if fah_morn <= 79:
    print("This morning is cold")
elif fah_morn <= 90:
    print("It is a little warm this morning")
else:
    print("It is quite hot today")

cel_eve = float(input("Enter evening temperature in degrees:"))
fah_eve = (9/5 * cel_eve) + 32
print("Temperature in Fahrenheit ", fah_eve)

if fah_eve <= 79:
    print("Tonight is cold")
elif fah_eve <= 90:
    print("It is a little warm this evening")
else:
    print("It is quite hot tonight")


if fah_morn and fah_eve <= 79:
    print("It was cold today")
elif 80 < fah_morn < 91 or 80 < fah_eve < 91:
    print("The weather was warm today")
else:
    print("Today was quite hot today")
```

temp()